# When organizing a conference on Underline.io, what determines if the videos will be later accessible for free to anyone?

Tags: conference, audio-video-recording, paywall

https://underline.io/ is a video platform giving access to lectures from conferences. This is not a spam, I have no affiliations with them.

Some academic conferences such as AAAI 2023 and ACL 2023 use Underline.io to host their videos. I see that some videos are accessible for free to anyone, and some videos are not accessible for free to anyone (one needs to pay to access them).

When organizing a conference on Underline.io, what determines if the videos will be later accessible for free to anyone?

---

Example of a video  accessible for free to anyone: https://underline.io/lecture/77209-crosssum-beyond-english-centric-cross-lingual-summarization-for-1-500-language-pairs

Examples of a video that is not accessible for free to anyone (one needs to pay to access it): https://underline.io/lecture/69312-robustloc-robust-camera-pose-regression-in-challenging-driving-environments

[image]

https://underline.io/lecture/41697-demystifying-open-access:

[image]

Comment: I am still interested in this question.

Comment: Any idea is welcome.